# Hydration Error. Expected server HTML to contain a matching <img> in <div>

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hydration

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI
> does not match what was rendered on the server.
>
> Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching `<img>` in
> `<div>`.

```js
"use client"
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { BeatLoader } from "react-spinners";
 
const SendEmail = ({setVisible}) => {
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
 
return (
    <div className="space-y-6 xl:space-y-7 max-w-[440px] m-auto p-1 mt-20">
      <div className="text-center text-xl md:text-3xl font-light">
Promeni šifru
      </div>
      <div className="p-5 border bg-white rounded-md">
        <div className="grid gap-1">
          {/* <div className="text-white p-2 bg-red-600 rounded-md mb-2" role="alert"
          
alo
          </div> */}
          <div className="m-auto">
            <div className="w-[80px] h-[80px] rounded-full overflow-hidden relative">
              {user && (
                <img
src={`${user.picture}`}
alt="Profile Picture"
className="w-full h-full object-fit-cover"
                />
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <p className="text-center">
            {user && `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`}
          </p>
          <button type="submit" className="p-3 bg-zelena hover:bg-zelena/90 border-2 rounded-lg w-full font-semibold text-white"
          >
            {/* {!loading && "Pošalji kod za promenu šifre"} */}
            <BeatLoader color="#111b2c" loading={true} cssOverride={override} size={7} aria-label="Loading Spinner" data-testid="loader"  />
          </button>
          <button onClick={()=>{
setVisible(0);
          }}
type="submit"
className="p-3 bg-white hover:bg-slate-100 border border-fejk-crna/50 rounded-md w-full font-semibold text-fejk-crna"
          >Nisi ti?</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SendEmail;
```

I tried to make it "use client" ,i tried this: `import dynamic from "next/dynamic"; export default dynamic (() => Promise.resolve(SendEmail), {ssr: false})` , but for every solution this error comes back...I cant find any temporary solution.